# My website is visible only through direct URL but not via the domain name I bought

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, shared-hosting

I have bought hosting and domain name separately, later when I'm buying hosting I have linked hosting to the domain name I bought. Now after hosting all the files by uploading them to the CPanel 11 file manager the website is not coming live. Instead it is being redirected to some ww2."mydomainname".com. But I can access my site by direct URL provided by the cpanel 11 hosting which is "mydomainname.md-48.webhostbox.net".

Comment: DNS takes time to propagate. How long ago did you link the domain name to point to the hosting? Also if you do nslookup on the "Domainname" do you get the correct IP address of the hosting? Also are you sure when you point the domain name to the hosting, you are using the exact address? (example: www.mydomainname-webhostbox.net is different to mydomainname-webhosbox.net and can point to different address)

Comment: 2 hours and yes nslookup is showing the correct IP address.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

DNS propagation takes up to 24-48 hours to propagate. You will have to make sure the following:

- Make sure that you have set correct nameservers
- Make sure that DNS zone if configured properly for your domain
- If your domain is resolving correct IP address and still it does not work, only your web host can investigate the issue and fix it.

Comment: There are many ways to check what you say. First the "propagation" of a dns does not take 24 hours to XX, but depends on factors such as the change is automatic. Personal factors are the team that makes the query.

Comment: if the person makes a dig <domain> or nslooup <domain> from your computer, you can know whether or not resolved.

Comment: @ Abdel Karim Mateos Sanchez 24-48 hours is ideal time for propagation. DNS propagation depends on many factors.. In most case they are propagated in few hours but it can take up to 48 hours. I am not sure why you so negative and made my post as not helpful.. I am not at all expecting, you up vote for it but the information is not even wrong. If you are FAQs, you will get same answer for DNS propagation.. This incident will be reported to moderators..

Comment: There're not "propagation" Resolution DNS not need "propagation". That it's a Hoster typical tip. At the same time we change a value in the name servers, it works. It is done. What does not? Everything depends on DNS to use the person who wants to check and time that fits that have cached DNS data from the last query. If you get 10 seconds of TTL, 10 seconds work with the new data. If you are not working up to 3 days within 3 days .... so it depends on the TTL area that domain in your DNS, and the time remaining of the DNS connection.

Comment: You can say what you want to do are free moderators. I am free to not accept the term as valid DNS Propagation and rate your answer as useless and incorrect. Have a nice day

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1912 it's best way for understand technical way DNS system